# importing data into cms/page in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I am trying to import data into cms/page using my own custom php code, when i try importing single static data the code works but when i try to import data by querying the database the code doesn't work.
 Code:

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);

Mage::app('default');



$coreResource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource') ; 


$read = $coreResource->getConnection('core_read');
    $query = "select *  from `".$coreResource->getTableName('sur_arts')."`,`".$coreResource->getTableName('sur_arts_store')."` where sur_arts.post_id=sur_arts_store.post_id ";

$result=$read->query($query);
foreach($result as $res)
{
$cmsPageData1 = array(
'title' => $res['title'],
'root_template' => 'three_columns',
'meta_keywords' => $res['meta_keywords'],
'meta_description' => $res['meta_description'],
'identifier' => $identifier,
'content_heading' => $res['title'],
'stores' => array(21),
'is_active'=>$res['status'],
'content' => $res['post_content']
 );


 Mage::getModel('cms/page')->setData($cmsPageData1)->save();
}
```

This did not work but if i try importing a single data with the same code it works

Can anybody help me, Please, Any help will be greatly appreciated, Thanking you in advance.

Comment: The lack of a space between the FROM and the table names probably doesn't help

Comment: It was a typo, but i can get the data :) i just cannot import it back to cms/pages.

Comment: What is $identifier ? You never defined this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento will only allow you to modify certain data from the "admin" backend.

You need to mimic this by adding this before you try to save to the database using the Magento Object Model:

```
Mage::app('default');
// Add just below this should be fine.
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
```

It would be good practice to add a try / catch block around your save too, and then do something with the errors, logging them etc.

Comment: The problem was in the Url key , there were some unwanted characters in the url key which was throwing exception error. @Andrew: Thank you for the help i really appreaciate it.